# What function annotation flags are available for Coverity Scan?

Tags: code-analysis, static-code-analysis, coverity

The Coverity Scan [tuning documentation](https://scan.coverity.com/tune) talks about adding function annotations to source files. There are three options listed:

- `+kill`
- `+alloc`
- `+free`

However, from that same page there is a link to an example file that uses as-of-yet unseen flags:

- [`toctou`](https://github.com/ukyg9e5r6k7gubiekd6/gpsd/blob/master/gpsdctl.c#L70)
- [`string_size`](https://github.com/ukyg9e5r6k7gubiekd6/gpsd/blob/master/gpsdctl.c#L103)

What do these flags mean? What other flags are available for function annotation, and where are they documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the content between the brackets should be the Coverity event tag name. The comment should immediately precede the line with the false positive in it, and will cause that defect to be flagged as intentional (as long as it matches the flagged event.)

For example, the `toctou` event tag name is detailed [here](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html).

[Source](https://doclazy.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/coverity-suppressing-false-positives-with-cod/)